# Gitlab shell runner cannot upload artifacts larger than 63KB : "501 Not Implemented"

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm having trouble using job artifacts with Gitlab CI.

I'm working on dockerized web app. I run the app with docker-compose and run some tests on it.
When the tests fail, the test framework takes a few screenshots. I then copy the screenshots to the build directory, and try to upload them as artifacts, but I get the following:

```
Uploading artifacts...
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=6560 revision=d0b76032 version=12.0.2
src/tests/_output/: found 5 matching files         
WARNING: Uploading artifacts to coordinator... failed  id=11975 responseStatus=501 Not Implemented status=501 Not Implemented token=EyreCNs7
WARNING: Retrying...                                error=invalid argument
WARNING: Uploading artifacts to coordinator... failed  id=11975 responseStatus=501 Not Implemented status=501 Not Implemented token=EyreCNs7
WARNING: Retrying...                                error=invalid argument
WARNING: Uploading artifacts to coordinator... failed  id=11975 responseStatus=501 Not Implemented status=501 Not Implemented token=EyreCNs7
FATAL: invalid argument                            
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Here's the stage configuration:

```
upload_screenshots:
  stage: upload_screenshots
  script:
    - docker cp myapp_php_test:/var/www/html/myapp/tests/_output/. src/tests/_output/
  when: on_failure
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - src/tests/_output/
    expire_in: 1 week
```

I made a test project that simply creates a text file and uploads it as an artifact, and it works as expected:

```
test:
  script: 
    - echo "test" > test.txt
    - ls -la
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - test.txt
    expire_in: 1 week
```

```
$ echo "test" > test.txt
Uploading artifacts...
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=101330 revision=d0b76032 version=12.0.2
test.txt: found 1 matching files                   
Uploading artifacts to coordinator... ok            id=11946 responseStatus=201 Created token=xmkvqina
Job succeeded
```

I'm running Gitlab CE 11.3.5 (c74e8d9) and Gitlab Runner 12.0.2 (d0b76032). The respective servers are not on the same subnetwork. I thought it might be our proxy but I don't know how to make sure of that. Besides, my test project works.

How can I debug this?
Is there a way use the artifact-uploader verbose mode from the gitlab-ci configuration?

### Update

It appears to be a file size issue. For some reason, I cannot upload files larger than 63KB.

```
stages:
  - passes
  - fails

passes:
  stage: passes
  when: always
  script:
    - dd if=/dev/urandom of=test.dat  bs=63K  count=1
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "*.dat"

fails:
  stage: fails
  when: always
  script:
    - dd if=/dev/urandom of=test.dat  bs=64K  count=1
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "*.dat"
```

Comment: Try to change - src/tests/_output/ to - src/tests/_output/*

Comment: @ilia I tried multiples syntaxes already. With and without wildcard, with and without quotes... They all work in my test project, but not in the other one.

Comment: well, i checked my configs and found out that I always referencing artifacts as i.e. report*.txt, mean some prefix before wildcard...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *was* the freaking proxy 
After setting the `no_proxy` environment variable in the CI settings to our internal subdomain, artifact uploading works as expected.
The variable can also be set in `/etc/systemd/system/gitlab-runner.service.d/http-proxy.conf` as stated in [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/proxy.html#adding-proxy-variables-to-the-runner-config):

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.my.domain.org:8080/"
Environment="NO_PROXY=my.domain.org"
```